# Windows media player overwrite on new edited playlist

Tags: windows-media-player, metadata, playlists, overwrite

I don't know what's wrong with Windows Media Player metadata over playlists.

When I trying to relocate some new songs to its new location using notepad++ (So that it could find and play them), Windows media player overwrites on those edits!
I din't have this bug before and I haven't done any change on its setting so far!

[image]

Comment: Is the media player running when you are making the notepad++ edits?

Comment: I suggest that you first move the actual song files on disk and let WMP's library pick up the move (check the `File Path` column). Do you still see the same behavior if you edit the playlist afterwards? (provided that it hasn't been updated already with the new location by WMP)

Comment: Hi DavidPostill ! No of course it's not running! i even checked the task manager.

Comment: Dear Tim De Baets! yes, apparently it worked! i only needed to let WPM to pick the songs up in its library! i couldn't believe how it lost its indexing through editing playlists. Anyway Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As dear Tim De Baets said, the only way was to delete whole previous indexing in from WMP library and update the indexing from the beginning. (Organize -> Manage Libraries -> Music).